# Basic question about conduction current

Tags: basic

Sorry for my english and long post again.

After reading [this](https://zhfirouzeh.iut.ac.ir/sites/zhfirouzeh.iut.ac.ir/files//files_course/what_makes_an_electric_current_flow.pdf) article, I realized that my understanding seemed to be wrong.

I thought that to create conduction current in some wire first we need a "charging" current - a current that will create voltage by build up charges on surface of the wire. These surface charges then create weak electric field inside the wire that drive conduction current (i.e. conduction current will appear *only after* "charging" process).

In other words, I considered these "charging" currents (e.g. if voltage is changed) to be completely independent of the conduction current.

But in above mentioned article W. G. V. Rosser describes what will happen with wires connected to generator if voltage of the generator will increase:

> ...Transient currents again flow in the connecting wire in the
>   direction of extra field ΔE. There is again some current flow towards
>   the surface of connecting wire until more charge builds up on the
>   surface of the wire and "guides" the extra current along the
>   connecting wire...
>
> ...However, the changes in electric field field intensity (and the
>   associated changes in potential and conduction current) are generally
>   propagates with a velocity comparable to, but less than the velocity
>   of light.

Besides that, after first glance on transmission line theory it turned out that pulse on it consist of both voltage and current. And it seems that the exact value of current already takes into account current required to charge wires to some voltage:

> When increasing the capacitance of a double line, some additional
>   electrons are necessary to keep up at given voltage. Therefore the
>   current I is increased in relation to V, corresponding to a decrease
>   of Z = V/I.

So, now I can't understand how all this related.

**Question:**

It seems that I should not separate a currents and it is not necessary to wait for the completion of the transients to get changes in conduction current.

Instead, some change in voltage (assume it increased) propagate down a wires *simultaneously* with corresponding change in conduction current. And some part of this conduction current is "spent" on charging the wires to given voltage. Additionally, as these surface charges accumulates during propagation process, they amplify electric field inside the wires to maintain the increased conduction current at this new level.

Is this new description correсt ?

Comment: There are errors in your quotes that may be changing the meaning -you should quote what is there accurately...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cable and you connect a voltage source to its other say left end between the wires the +pole pulls some electrons and the minus pole pushes them because the voltage source actually generates an electric field (the field adapts to all geometries as needed, only the voltage stays the same in the source if it is a voltage source)

The effect spreads by electric influence as you have red. That's because moved electrons in wire metal cause charge imbalance and it's a source of new electric field which moves electrons.

But how fast the effect spreads along the cable? Transmission line theory gives to us formulas for it. The effect spreads along the cable as a wave. It contains both voltage and current components. That's because both are needed. Charge imbalance can propagate only if some electrons move along the wires.

Finally there appears a voltage at the other end of the cable and if there's a load it takes current as it's operating law (for ex. Ohm's law) states. Transmission line theory shows also that a wave can reflect. That happens if the voltage and current components of the arriving wave do not both fit into the load at the same time, their ratio (=impedance) is different for the wave and the load.

Deeper investigation of what there happens must take into the account also fields around the wires of the cable. Classic Heaviside's transmission line theory squeezes them to the inductance and capacitance of the line. Exact analysis with Maxwell's field theory shows that the wave actually exists in the space around the wires, the possibility of current in the metal creates a boundary condition which directs the wave along the cable. That's lucky because we really expect to get something to our load at the end of the cable. When the wires are short when compared to the wavelength no special design is needed, 2 wires are enough. Longer wires need to be parallel to avoid losing some energy as radiated wave to the space and to avoid reflections before the wave arrives to the load.

All wires are not built to feed a load. For ex. antenna builders hope that the wave jumps into the air as completely as possible.

You have seen something right when you built your charging current idea. A wave must propagate along the cable from the connected source to the load before the load can get anything and the wave propagates along the cable because there's plenty of electrons which are bound very loosely in their atoms.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, current only moves if there is a change in voltage and flows from a higher voltage to a lower one. There is only one current in this case.

In the case of a capacitor, current flows in and out of the device only when there is a change in voltage on the terminals, otherwise the current through the device is zero.

In most cases there is a voltage source which creates a voltage difference and the current flows back to the source.

With static voltages (sometimes physical processes), you can get current without a 'circuit' and return flow back to the source.